# Why does warfarin decrease biological activity of protein C?

Tags: biochemistry, pharmacology, medicine

Warfarin inhibits VKOR. Hence it disrupts vitamin K dependent $\gamma$-carboxylation of Fc- II, VII, IX, X.

But what exactly it does to Protein C and Protein S? How does it also affect anticoagulant system?

[Ref. Kim, Yesel, and Oh Young Bang. “Paradoxical Procoagulant Effect of Early Doses of Warfarin: Possible Role of Non-Vitamin K Oral Anticoagulant in Patients with Atrial Fibrillation-Related Stroke.” Journal of stroke vol. 17,2 (2015): 216-8. doi:10.5853/jos.2015.17.2.216

[https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4460341/]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4460341/%5D)

I couldn't find an article regarding the mechanism of this inhibition. Any help will be appreciated.